# Hibernate Envers "InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The associated entity manager is closed"

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, entitymanager, hibernate-envers

I have a service (controller) that has a logic in it and creates transaction for underlaying DAO Objects.

In one of the method, I read entity from the database and then trying to find it's historical versions with the Hibernate Envers.

```
@Named
@Transactional
public class DocCtrl {
  ...

public synchronized List<DocCreateRespDTO> getUnapprovedVersions() {
        List<Task> unapprovedTasks = taskDAO.getForApproval();

        List<DocCreateRespDTO> unapprovedDocDTOS = new ArrayList<>(unapprovedTasks.size());

        for (Task u : unapprovedTasks) {
            ...

            rp.setManipulationCtx(dto.document, active.getId());

            unapprovedDocDTOS.add(dto);
        }

        return unapprovedDocDTOS;
    }

}
```

`rp` is injected instance of `RevisionProvider`:

```
@Repository
public class RevisionProvider {

    @PersistenceContext(name = Vedantas.PU_NAME, type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private AuditReader auditReader;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public OperationCtx getCreationRevisionFor(Class aClass, long id) {
        final Object[] array = (Object[]) auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.ADD))
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getSingleResult();

        return ((OperationCtx) array[1]);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public OperationCtx getLastRevisionFor(Class aClass, long id) {
        final Object[] array = (Object[]) auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().maximize()
                        .computeAggregationInInstanceContext()
                )
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getSingleResult();

        OperationCtx lastchg = (OperationCtx) array[1];
        OperationCtx creation = getCreationRevisionFor(aClass, id);

        if (creation.getId() == lastchg.getId())
            return new OperationCtx();

        return lastchg;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List getHistoryFor(Class aClass, String pk, String val) {
        List res = auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.property(pk).eq(val))
                .getResultList();

        return res;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void setManipulationCtx(FindDTO dto, long id) {
        OperationCtx cctx = getCreationRevisionFor(DocVersion.class, id);
        OperationCtx lctx = getLastRevisionFor(Metadata.class, dto.metadata.getId());

        dto.createCtx = ModelCopyHelper.copyOperCtx(cctx);
        dto.lastChangeCtx = ModelCopyHelper.copyOperCtx(lctx);
    }
}
```

Now what happens when the executor hits `auditReader.createQuery()` is that 
`WARNING: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The associated entity manager is closed!;` is being thrown.

As you can see I tried to annotate each method a transactional to make spring inject/start the transaction and open the entity manager but still that exception is being thrown.

Can you advice how correctly inject the entity manager here?

Framework versions being used:
Hibernate: 5.2.9.Final
Envers: 5.2.12.Final

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you're using Spring in this context with its default bean definition; therefore you cannot create a stateful bean and cache it as an instance variable in a stateless bean and reuse it across state boundaries in this way.   This is why you get the error.

What you need to do is delay the construction of the `AuditReader` until you need it.  This guarantees that the underlying `EntityManager` is open for that thread of execution.

In short, you need to do this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public OperationCtx getCreationRevisionFor(Class aClass, long id) {
  final AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get( entityManager );
  // do whatever you need with the reader here.
}
```

Comment: no, I was too eager and forgot to unset "PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED". even with your solution when I set context as transactional it gives the same error back